# Is it possible to disable DoneInProc tokens in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, network

I have a PLC library that isn't able to parse the return packet from MSSQL when it includes `DoneInProc` tokens before the `ColumnMetaData` and `Row` data. I've contacted the author of the library, but he hasn't responded and I need a fix. My searches show that this can be done in Sybase, but I can't find anything for doing the same in MSSQL.

Is it possible to configure MS SQL Server 2019 to not send the `DoneInProc` tokens when executing stored procedures?

[DoneInProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/43e891c5-f7a1-432f-8f9f-233c4cd96afb)

Comment: The linked answer contains the only mechanism for suppressing DoneInProc messages: SET NOCOUNT ON.

Comment: The lack of `_` in my search term prevented me finding the answer. Many thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I don't know your roll at Microsoft, but if it is possible having the NOCOUNT docs have both DONE_IN_PROC and DONEINPROC might make this more searchable.

Comment: Good point.  I don't own the docs, but they're on GitHub, so I created a Pull Request to update that doc page. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/7110

Comment: The PR was accepted and the docs have been updated. Thanks for pointing that out!